# evaluating/accessing a structure

Tags: c, gcc, struct, volatile

Consider the two slightly different versions of the same code:

```
struct s
{
  int dummy[1];
};

volatile struct s s;

int main(void)
{
  s;
  return 0;
}
```

and

```
struct s
{
  int dummy[16];
};

volatile struct s s;

int main(void)
{
  s;
  return 0;
}
```

Here's what I'm getting with gcc 4.6.2 for them:

```
_main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        andl    $-16, %esp
        call    ___main
        movl    _s, %eax
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        leave
        ret

        .comm   _s, 4, 2
```

and

```
_main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        andl    $-16, %esp
        call    ___main
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        leave
        ret

        .comm   _s, 64, 5
```

Please note the absence of access to `s` in the second case.

Is it a compiler bug or am I just dealing with the following statement of the C standard and the gcc developers simply chose such a weird implementation-definedness and are still playing by the rules?:

> What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined.

What would be the reason for this difference? I'd naturally expect the whole structre being accessed (or not accessed, I'm not sure), irrespective of its size and of what's inside it.

P.S. What does your compiler (non-gcc or newer gcc) do in this case? (*please answer this last question in a comment* if that's the only part you're going to address, as this isn't the main question being asked, but more of a curiosity question).

Comment: I just tried with GCC 4.8.0, and it does similar:  The 1 word version still gets a single read, but the 16 word version does not.  If I say "s=s", though, even the 16-entry struct gets a copy.

Comment: This is interesting: The GCC 4.6.0 manual specifically calls out _scalar volatiles_, while the GCC 4.0.4 manual does not (two I happened to find quickly with google).  4.6.0:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Volatiles.html   4.0.4:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Volatiles.html   In your example, the struct with a single int is "scalar", while the one with 16 ints is not.

Comment: @JoeZ I'm not accessing scalars that are inside the structure, I'm accessing the whole structure (or so I think).

Comment: Right, but I believe GCC converts a struct that fits within a register to a scalar access.  ie. `struct { int x[1]; }` gets treated as a scalar in many contexts.  I don't think that's guaranteed, mind you, and appears to be an implementation artifact if you ask me.  Maybe you should ask on the GCC developer lists?

Comment: Can this be [related](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47409#c12)?

Comment: What is in eax?, it looks like the volatile is initialised when can be treated as an integer but it is not when it must be treated as an array, it would make sense because in the first time it won't cost that much but it will in the second.

Comment: @Jekyll `s` is initialized with all zeroes by the time `main()` starts.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze so my thought makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between C and C++ for this question which explains what's going on.

## clang-3.4

When compiling either of these snippets as C++, the emitted assembly didn't reference s in either case. In fact a warning was issued for both:

`volatile.c:8:2: warning: expression result unused; assign into a variable to force a volatile load [-Wunused-volatile-lvalue]
        s;`

These warnings were not issued when compiling in C99 mode. As mentioned in [this blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/) and [this GCC wiki entry from the question comments](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Volatiles.html), using `s` in this context causes an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in C, but not in C++. This is confirmed by examining the Clang AST for C, as there is an ImplicitCastExpr from LvalueToRValue, which does not exist in the AST generated from C++. (The AST is not affected by the size of the struct).

A quick grep of the Clang source reveals this in the emission of aggregate expressions:

```
case CK_LValueToRValue:
// If we're loading from a volatile type, force the destination
// into existence.
if (E->getSubExpr()->getType().isVolatileQualified()) {
  EnsureDest(E->getType());
  return Visit(E->getSubExpr());
}
```

`EnsureDest` forces the emission of a stack slot, sized and typed for the expression. As the optimizers are not allowed to remove volatile accesses, they remain as a scalar load/store and a memcpy respectively in both the IR and output asm. This is the behavior I would expect, given the above.

## gcc-4.8.2

Here, I observe the same behavior as in the question. However when I change the expression from `s;` to `s.dummy;`, the access does not appear in either version. I'm not familiar with the internals of gcc as I am with LLVM so I can't speculate why this would happen. But based on the above observations, I would say this is a compiler bug due to inconsistency.

Comment: Thank you. I think the gcc developers can get away with the inconsistency because evaluating whole structures (without assigning them to one another) is something of rare occurrence, low practical importance (not to mention the fact that potentially lots of memory or code or CPU cycles may be needed to read a structure from memory and that it's unclear how union members should be read) and the standard unequivocally says `What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined.` I don't think the matter can or needs to be further clarified.